# Using "Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework", how to set a bubble's diameter in a dynamically generated bubble chart?

Tags: .net, charts

m_chart.Series("TestSeries").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble
m_chart.Series("TestSeries").MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle

m_chart.Series("Default").Points. ...

at this point, how can i set x, y and diameter values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diameter, try:

```
m_chart.Series("TestSeries").MarkerSize
```

Then:

```
m_chart.Series("TestSeries").Points.Add(new DataPoint...)
```

If you want one point to have a different bubble diameter, you'll probably have to make it a separate series with its own properties.

Answer (score 4):

That's the second Y-value on the bubble chart:

```
m_chart.Series("TestSeries").Points.Add(x, y, diameter)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456658.aspx